Java OpenApi / Swagger Shopware 6 Client
I am encountering some trouble while generating a OpenApi Client for Shopware 6
we got a openapi defintion via shopware, in the first part we were working with the "small" client which has something like 30k lines of formatted json.
But some relevant endpoints were missing and we needed the "full" admin client by adding "jsonapi" in the ending of the openapi-json url. This openapi-definition comes with a whopping ~94k lines of formatted json and when Running the openapi generator (Linux, Mac, Windows via Shell or Maven we encountered a lot of IllegalStateExceptions like this:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: TextBuffer overrun: size reached (2147527247) exceeds maximum of 2147483647
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer._reportBufferOverflow(TextBuffer.java:1165)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.expand(TextBuffer.java:1099)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.append(TextBuffer.java:783)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.SegmentedStringWriter.write(SegmentedStringWriter.java:63)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator._flushBuffer(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:2060)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator.writeRaw(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:618)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultIndenter.writeIndentation(DefaultIndenter.java:94)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultPrettyPrinter.writeObjectEntrySeparator(DefaultPrettyPrinter.java:338)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator._writePPFieldName(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:369)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator._writeFieldName(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:172)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator.writeFieldName(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:155)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdKeySerializers$StringKeySerializer.serialize(StdKeySerializers.java:302)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdKeySerializers$Dynamic.serialize(StdKeySerializers.java:264)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeOptionalFields(MapSerializer.java:868)


After researching i couldnt really find a solution to the problem. So my question is: are we the only ones encountering the trouble of not being able to generate a openapi java client for shopware 6?
What i tryed:

Changing the fasterxml implementation in the openapi-packages (i used various versions from 6.0.x to 6.2.1)
Changing the openapi version (see above)
Using different OS (Linux, Mac, Windows)
Converting the json with https://editor-next.swagger.io/ to a yaml

after converting it to yaml i still had to execute the following actions to get a client that compiles:

Remove duplicate Lines with regex: ^( *- .+)\n(\1\n)+
Remove oAuth and oauthPassword from SecuritySchemes
Deactivate in maven JsonNullable
Set Java Version to 17 in pom.xml
Remove Method "setId" from generated Snippet Class
Add Constructor to generated Link Class
Adjust imports in generated LocaleApi Class

after that i had a compiling client which i could package. But of course there were Problems with the client aswell..:
When using the Client it would send propert Requests but the Response e.g. for Products was not mapped with all values from the response json:
Response Json:
{
  "data": {
    "id": "018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc",
    "type": "product",
    "attributes": {
      "versionId": "0fa91ce3e96a4bc2be4bd9ce752c3425",
      "parentId": null,
      "parentVersionId": null,
      "manufacturerId": "018e51cb417470f98cb72930aaaed8de",
      "productManufacturerVersionId": null,
      "unitId": null,
      "taxId": "018e51cb4159729287b69d36497bc7bd",
      "coverId": null,
      "productMediaVersionId": null,
      "deliveryTimeId": null,
      "featureSetId": "018e51cb52b37124975143d1473c6b8c",
      "canonicalProductId": null,
      "cmsPageId": null,
      "cmsPageVersionId": null,
      "price": [
        {
          "extensions": [],
          "currencyId": "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca",
          "net": 84.033613445378,
          "gross": 100.0,
          "linked": true,
          "listPrice": null,
          "percentage": null,
          "regulationPrice": null
        }
      ],
      "productNumber": "SW10000",
      "restockTime": null,
      "autoIncrement": 1,
      "active": true,
      "available": true,
      "isCloseout": false,
      "variation": [],
      "displayGroup": "e66a2ed626bca965718e530a57e5bd55",
      "variantListingConfig": {
        "extensions": [],
        "displayParent": null,
        "mainVariantId": null,
        "configuratorGroupConfig": null
      },
      "variantRestrictions": null,
      "manufacturerNumber": null,
      "ean": null,
      "purchaseSteps": 1,
      "maxPurchase": null,
      "minPurchase": 1,
      "purchaseUnit": null,
      "referenceUnit": null,
      "shippingFree": false,
      "purchasePrices": [
        {
          "extensions": [],
          "currencyId": "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca",
          "net": 0.0,
          "gross": 0.0,
          "linked": true,
          "listPrice": null,
          "percentage": null,
          "regulationPrice": null
        }
      ],
      "markAsTopseller": false,
      "weight": null,
      "width": null,
      "height": null,
      "length": null,
      "releaseDate": null,
      "ratingAverage": null,
      "categoryTree": [
        "018e51cb415b70c8963fb76c443e33b0",
        "018e51d25cd07ffbaa5ba57b26b1686d"
      ],
      "propertyIds": [
        "018e51d081057822ae56f8b4edbf3fcf"
      ],
      "optionIds": null,
      "streamIds": null,
      "tagIds": null,
      "categoryIds": [
        "018e51d25cd07ffbaa5ba57b26b1686d"
      ],
      "childCount": 0,
      "customFieldSetSelectionActive": null,
      "sales": 0,
      "states": [
        "is-physical"
      ],
      "metaDescription": null,
      "name": "Container 30165",
      "keywords": null,
      "description": null,
      "metaTitle": null,
      "packUnit": null,
      "packUnitPlural": null,
      "customFields": {
        "cogoshop_product_incl_days_in_container_rent": 10,
        "cogoshop_product_price_per_additional_rent_day": 2.9,
        "cogoshop_product_lead_time": 22,
        "cogoshop_product_max_positioning_time": 14,
        "cogoshop_product_max_lead_time": 34,
        "cogoshop_product_area": "Hannover",
        "cogoshop_product_request_delivery_date": true,
        "cogoshop_product_request_delivery_time": true,
        "cogoshop_product_request_collection_date": true,
        "cogoshop_product_offer_delivery_authorization": true,
        "cogoshop_product_offer_noparkingzone": true,
        "cogoshop_product_need_zipcode_check": true,
        "cogoshop_product_deliveryday_monday": true,
        "cogoshop_product_deliveryday_tuesday": true,
        "cogoshop_product_deliveryday_wednesday": true,
        "cogoshop_product_deliveryday_thursday": true,
        "cogoshop_product_deliveryday_friday": true,
        "cogoshop_product_container_id": "M07",
        "cogoshop_product_container_type": "Mulde",
        "cogoshop_product_price_group": "1",
        "cogoshop_product_dispo_group": "M"
      },
      "slotConfig": null,
      "customSearchKeywords": null,
      "availableStock": 0,
      "stock": 0,
      "createdAt": "2024-03-18T13:49:14.365+00:00",
      "updatedAt": "2024-04-03T11:44:41.107+00:00",
      "translated": {
        "metaDescription": null,
        "name": "Container 30165",
        "keywords": null,
        "description": null,
        "metaTitle": null,
        "packUnit": null,
        "packUnitPlural": null,
        "customFields": {
          "cogoshop_product_incl_days_in_container_rent": 10,
          "cogoshop_product_price_per_additional_rent_day": 2.9,
          "cogoshop_product_lead_time": 22,
          "cogoshop_product_max_positioning_time": 14,
          "cogoshop_product_max_lead_time": 34,
          "cogoshop_product_area": "Hannover",
          "cogoshop_product_request_delivery_date": true,
          "cogoshop_product_request_delivery_time": true,
          "cogoshop_product_request_collection_date": true,
          "cogoshop_product_offer_delivery_authorization": true,
          "cogoshop_product_offer_noparkingzone": true,
          "cogoshop_product_need_zipcode_check": true,
          "cogoshop_product_deliveryday_monday": true,
          "cogoshop_product_deliveryday_tuesday": true,
          "cogoshop_product_deliveryday_wednesday": true,
          "cogoshop_product_deliveryday_thursday": true,
          "cogoshop_product_deliveryday_friday": true,
          "cogoshop_product_container_id": "M07",
          "cogoshop_product_container_type": "Mulde",
          "cogoshop_product_price_group": "1",
          "cogoshop_product_dispo_group": "M"
        },
        "slotConfig": null,
        "customSearchKeywords": null
      },
      "apiAlias": "product_foreign_keys_extension"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "downloads": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/downloads"
        }
      },
      "parent": {
        "data": null,
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/parent"
        }
      },
      "children": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/children"
        }
      },
      "deliveryTime": {
        "data": null,
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/delivery-time"
        }
      },
      "tax": {
        "data": {
          "type": "tax",
          "id": "018e51cb4159729287b69d36497bc7bd"
        },
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/tax"
        }
      },
      "manufacturer": {
        "data": null,
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/manufacturer"
        }
      },
      "unit": {
        "data": null,
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/unit"
        }
      },
      "cover": {
        "data": null,
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/cover"
        }
      },
      "featureSet": {
        "data": null,
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/feature-set"
        }
      },
      "cmsPage": {
        "data": null,
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/cms-page"
        }
      },
      "canonicalProduct": {
        "data": null,
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/canonical-product"
        }
      },
      "prices": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/prices"
        }
      },
      "media": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/media"
        }
      },
      "crossSellings": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/cross-sellings"
        }
      },
      "crossSellingAssignedProducts": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/cross-selling-assigned-products"
        }
      },
      "configuratorSettings": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/configurator-settings"
        }
      },
      "visibilities": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/visibilities"
        }
      },
      "searchKeywords": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/search-keywords"
        }
      },
      "productReviews": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/product-reviews"
        }
      },
      "mainCategories": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/main-categories"
        }
      },
      "seoUrls": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/seo-urls"
        }
      },
      "orderLineItems": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/order-line-items"
        }
      },
      "wishlists": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/wishlists"
        }
      },
      "options": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/options"
        }
      },
      "properties": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/properties"
        }
      },
      "categories": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/categories"
        }
      },
      "streams": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/streams"
        }
      },
      "categoriesRo": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/categories-ro"
        }
      },
      "tags": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/tags"
        }
      },
      "customFieldSets": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/custom-field-sets"
        }
      },
      "translations": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc\/translations"
        }
      }
    },
    "meta": null
  },
  "included": [
    {
      "id": "018e51cb4159729287b69d36497bc7bd",
      "type": "tax",
      "attributes": {
        "taxRate": 19.0,
        "name": "Standard rate",
        "position": 1,
        "customFields": null,
        "createdAt": "2024-03-18T14:40:58.841+00:00",
        "updatedAt": null,
        "apiAlias": "tax_foreign_keys_extension"
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/tax\/018e51cb4159729287b69d36497bc7bd"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "products": {
          "data": [],
          "links": {
            "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/tax\/018e51cb4159729287b69d36497bc7bd\/products"
          }
        },
        "rules": {
          "data": [],
          "links": {
            "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/tax\/018e51cb4159729287b69d36497bc7bd\/rules"
          }
        },
        "shippingMethods": {
          "data": [],
          "links": {
            "related": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/tax\/018e51cb4159729287b69d36497bc7bd\/shipping-methods"
          }
        }
      },
      "meta": null
    }
  ],
  "links": {
    "self": "https:\/\/sw6.web.io\/api\/product\/018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc"
  }
}

Product-Instance:
class CreateProduct200Response {
    meta: {}
    links: class SuccessLinks {
        first: null
        last: null
        prev: null
        next: null
    }
    data: class Product {
        id: 018e51d1a36a729d83e675645d22b0bc
        versionId: null
        parentId: null
        parentVersionId: null
        manufacturerId: null
        productManufacturerVersionId: null
        unitId: null
        taxId: null
        coverId: null
        productMediaVersionId: null
        deliveryTimeId: null
        featureSetId: null
        canonicalProductId: null
        cmsPageId: null
        cmsPageVersionId: null
        price: null
        productNumber: null
        restockTime: null
        autoIncrement: null
        active: null
        available: null
        isCloseout: null
        variation: null
        displayGroup: null
        variantListingConfig: null
        variantRestrictions: null
        manufacturerNumber: null
        ean: null
        purchaseSteps: null
        maxPurchase: null
        minPurchase: null
        purchaseUnit: null
        referenceUnit: null
        shippingFree: null
        purchasePrices: null
        markAsTopseller: null
        weight: null
        width: null
        height: null
        length: null
        releaseDate: null
        ratingAverage: null
        categoryTree: null
        propertyIds: null
        optionIds: null
        streamIds: null
        tagIds: null
        categoryIds: null
        childCount: null
        customFieldSetSelectionActive: null
        sales: null
        states: null
        metaDescription: null
        name: null
        keywords: null
        description: null
        metaTitle: null
        packUnit: null
        packUnitPlural: null
        customFields: null
        slotConfig: null
        customSearchKeywords: null
        availableStock: null
        stock: null
        createdAt: null
        updatedAt: null
        translated: null
        downloads: null
        parent: null
        children: null
        deliveryTime: null
        tax: null
        manufacturer: null
        unit: null
        cover: null
        featureSet: null
        cmsPage: null
        canonicalProduct: null
        prices: null
        media: null
        crossSellings: null
        crossSellingAssignedProducts: null
        configuratorSettings: null
        visibilities: null
        searchKeywords: null
        productReviews: null
        mainCategories: null
        seoUrls: null
        orderLineItems: null
        wishlists: null
        options: null
        properties: null
        categories: null
        streams: null
        categoriesRo: null
        tags: null
        customFieldSets: null
    }
    included: [class Resource {
        type: tax
        id: 018e51cb4159729287b69d36497bc7bd
        attributes: {taxRate=19.0, name=Standard rate, position=1, customFields=null, createdAt=2024-03-18T14:40:58.841+00:00, updatedAt=null, apiAlias=tax_foreign_keys_extension}
        relationships: class Relationships {
            links: null
            data: null
        }
        links: {self=class Link {
            href: https://sw6.web.io/api/tax/018e51cb4159729287b69d36497bc7bd
            meta: {}
        }}
        meta: null
    }]
}

i could not attach the json / yaml, but i will try to add them in the comments..

Anyone got an idea how i can provide these large files here?..
